# Unable to create a .gitignore file - Centos

Tags: git, centos, gitignore

I have created a new Repo remotely. Before I push the project to the remote repo I was wanting to create a `.gitignore` to ignore certain files.

The problem comes when I run:

- `touch .gitignore`
- `nano .gitignore`

I add the directories I'm wanting to ignore. When I save & exit, the file is non-existent.

How do I go about creating a `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to ls -a to view all files.

**-a** will show you also file started by a dot **.something**

Note : If you are in the git directory and do a **git status**, you will have also a new untraked file ".gitignore"